# Flask request returns None; but Ajax Post is successful

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask

In flask I'm using a GET request to first render a template and get data the user has selected.

```
@app.route('/surveys', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def register_form():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('survey_table.html')
    else:
        example = request.json
        return json.dumps(example)
```

This data (which is the #ids of checkboxes selected in a table) is then posted back to FLASK using an ajax Post request. Since the data was initially an array I have used JSON.stringify

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        var list = [];
        var checkBoxes = $('#surveyDetails').find("input[type='checkbox']:checked");
        checkBoxes.each(function() {
        var currentRow = this.parentNode.parentNode;
        list.push(currentRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].innerText);
        });
        // now names contains all of the names of checked checkboxes
        $.ajax({
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: '/surveys',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({'Hello': list}),
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("error!");
            }
        });   //end ajax
    });
});
```

**The Problem:**

I can see that the ajax post is executed successfully since I am able to see the selected ids as an alert once I click the submit button. However, in flask when I return this JSON object, I always get a null response.

I have already tried get_json(force=True). Still the same result.

Comment: pls post server side code

Comment: @kalai I've updated the server side code. Do let me know if you need more clarity on the issue

Comment: did you print the `return json.dumps(example)` instead of return?

Comment: @George, I tried return both `str(json.dumps(example))` and `print(json.dumps(example))`  ,  both return null

Comment: Use `json.loads(request.data)` instead of `request.json`

Comment: @Roman: `json.loads(request.data)` leads to a json.decoder error. Does this mean that the posted data is not coming through as expected?

Comment: Ah okay, probably you need the right encoding: `contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'`

Comment: Hi Maybe with request.form instead of request.json.